# Area 51 "vote to delete" rejection needs re-worded

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, wording, error-message

If you start a proposal and realize that its not going to gain traction, naturally, you'd want to delete it.

Some proposals gain enough traction to prevent that, and the "Sorry, you can't do that" message still relates to SO:

> "Sorry, this proposal cannot be
>   deleted: too many existing answers. or
>   upvoted/accepted answers"

While yes, it says proposal, I suggest `s/answers/example\ questions/` in the notification.

Tagging this as a bug, but it isn't really, I'm just not sure what else it could be tagged. Introducing <kbd>remnant-from-so-on-area51</kbd> seemed kind of silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wording for this message has been fixed. Thanks!

As you can probably guess, we globally replaced "question" with "proposal" in the SO codebase when starting Area 51 (this worked suprisingly well). We didn't do the same with "answer" --> "example question" (everything broke) so we were left with a few bugs like this one.

Comment: Damn you guys are getting faster every day! The whole front page is flooded with [status-completed]